# How can realloc be used effectively in loops?

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays, realloc

I'm new to c so sorry if the question might seem basic. I'm trying to read a string with unknown size from the user and store it in a dynamic array.
This program is going to make accounts for users but I can't successfully scan the username or the password.
Please note that no arrays with fixed size can be used.
Any solutions using files can be used and also be really helpful.

```
void main(){
    user *dummyUser = (user *) malloc(sizeof(user));
    dummyUser->next=NULL; 
    char* password=(char* )malloc(sizeof(char));
    char* name=(char* )malloc(sizeof(char));
    int i=0;
    char c;
    char ptr;
    while((c=getchar())!=' '){
        name[i]=c;
        ptr=(char *)realloc(name,sizeof(char));
        if(ptr==NULL){
            printf("realloc failed");
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
        i++;
    }
    i=0;
    while((c=getchar())!='\n'){
        password[i]=c;
        password=(char *)realloc(password,sizeof(char));
        i++;
    }
}
```

realloc seem to work for 1 time, but the next times it returns a null pointer and makes the program crash.
note: I know I have to check if realloc returns a null pointer, I checked it in my watchlist so I didn't write the related code.Thanks for helping.

Comment: Side note: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/12149471)

Comment: @pixiethepixel The variable ptr is declared as having the type char char ptr;. So this assignment ptr=(char *)realloc(name,sizeof(char)); does not make sense.

Comment: A single byte C string is a nearly useless C string. Tip: Don't use `realloc()` aggressively. Try and minimize the number of calls made.

Comment: Tip: Don't allocate one byte at a time. Read in the whole string into some sufficiently large buffer, figure out how much data is in the buffer, and then copy out of there into a correctly sized allocation. Use `strdup()` if you have it.

Comment: @pixiethepixel After you have updated your program the identifier ptr is undeclared.

Comment: You need `name = ptr;` after the reallocation.

Comment: Tip: Never forget to NUL terminate your strings!

Comment: @tadman I think he's trying to implement `getline()`, so he doesn't have to declare a "sufficiently large buffer".

Comment: @pixiethepixel And you are always allocating one character.

Comment: If `realloc` fails, you print an error message, but you continue program execution as if it succeeded. I suggest that you add `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );` underneath the line `printf("realloc failed");`.

Comment: @Barmar That's certainly an interpretation, but this implementation leaves a lot to be desired. A fixed-sized buffer is probably a better place to start. Dynamic allocation and resizing requires a lot more finesse.

Comment: @tadman True, but I think he's trying to learn how to handle input without arbitrary limits. It's a reasonable exercise.

Comment: Thanks for the help. @tadman the problem is that I can't store it in a large buffer, the data is needed to be handled with only dynamic arrays.

Comment: The return type of getchar is int for a reason.  You need to test it for EOF.

Comment: `char c;` then `while((c=getchar())!=' '){...}` has multiple issues.  First, `getchar()` returns `int`, not `char`, because `EOF` is an integer value that can not be represented as a `char`.  So your code can't reliably detect `EOF` even if it checked for `EOF` - which it doesn't.  And that's the second problem - if your code reaches `EOF` before a `' '` character, it falls into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't doing what you want:

```
ptr=(char *)realloc(name,sizeof(char));
```

The second argument of `realloc` specifies the *total* number of bytes you want allocated, not just how many *more* bytes to allocate.  You're not extending the array by 1 each time, you're just reallocating the same 1-byte space (`sizeof (char)` is 1 by definition).

Remember that to store an N-character string, you need to allocate *at least* N+1 bytes to account for the string terminator.

The typical way to do this is to double the size of the buffer each time - you'll need to keep track of the total buffer size as well as the number of bytes used, like so:

```
#include <ctype.h> // for the isspace call below:
...

size_t size = 2; // 2 bytes can store a 1-character string
char *name = malloc( size ); // no need for a cast
size_t i = 0;
int c;
...

/**
 * You'll probably want to break on EOF and *any* whitespace
 * character
 */
while( (c = getchar()) != EOF && !isspace( c ) )
{
  if ( i == size )
  {
    /**
     * Double the size of the buffer; again, no need for a cast
     *
     * Since realloc will return NULL if it can't extend the
     * buffer, we want to assign the result to a temporary;
     * otherwise we risk overwriting the pointer value in name
     * with a NULL pointer and losing our access to the memory
     * that's been previously allocated.
     */
    char *tmp = realloc( name, size * 2 ); 
    if ( tmp )
    {
      name = tmp;
      size *= 2;
    }
    else
    {
      /**
       * We were unable to extend the buffer; you can treat this
       * as a fatal error and exit immediately, or you can
       * try to proceed with the data you have.  The previous
       * buffer is still allocated at this point.  
       *
       * For this particular program, you'd probably just want
       * to exit with an error message at this point, like so:
       */
      fputs( "Failed to extend name buffer, exiting...", stderr );
      free( name ); // clean up what we've already allocated
      exit( 0 );
    } 
  }
  name[i++] = c;
}
name[i] = 0; // terminate the string
```

For convenience's sake, you'll want to move the buffer extension into its own function:

```
char *extend( char **buf, size_t *size )
{
  char *tmp = realloc( *buf, *size * 2 );
  if ( tmp )
  {
    *buf = tmp;
    *size *= 2;
  }
  return tmp;
}
```

and you'd call it as

```
while( (c = getchar()) != EOF && !isspace( c ) )
{
  if ( i == size )
  {
    if ( !extend( &name, &size ) )
    {
      // handle realloc failure
    }
  }
  name[i++] = c;
}
name[i] = 0; // terminate the string
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> ptr=(char *)realloc(name,sizeof(char));
> ```

Please note that this is allocating a single byte. You have done this several times. A C string is an array of characters with a null terminator (`'\0'`) byte at the end. An array that can only hold one byte can only ever hold an empty C string, *or* lack that null terminator, resulting in undefined behavior.

You likely want to start by allocating a more useful amount of space, and then grow exponentially as your input grows to avoid excessive calls to `realloc`.

E.g.

```
size_t allocated_bytes = 64;
char *name = malloc(allocated_bytes);
size_t read_bytes = 0;

char ch;

while ((ch = getchar()) != ' ') {
    if (read_bytes >= allocated_bytes - 1) {
        allocated_bytes *= 2;
        name = realloc(name, allocated_bytes);
    }

    name[read_bytes++] = ch;
}

name[read_bytes] = '\0';
```

*Checking the return of `realloc` and for EOF I leave as an exercise for the OP.*

Comment: You should error check the memory allocation calls — and `oldptr = realloc(oldptr, newsize);` is an anti-pattern.  You should use: `void *newptr = realloc(oldptr, newsize); if (newptr == NULL) { …handle memory allocation failure… } oldptr = newptr;` so that you still have a pointer to the old memory if allocation fails (so you can free it, for example).  I usually use `size_t newsize = oldsize * 2;` and only assign `newsize` to `oldsize` when the allocation worked.  If `oldsize` can start at `0` (rather than `64`), I use `size_t newsize = (oldsize + 2) * 2;` to get the sequence 4, 12, 28, etc.